# Rubymine Live Templates cheat sheet

Tags: rubymine, live-templates

Does anyone know if there is a cheat sheet available for the acronyms that trigger Live Templates in Rubymine?  For example "ifth" plus tab inserts an if-then-else clause.

Or does there exist a config file somewhere that I could print out? Searching haven't gotten me anywhere.

Comment: see http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/zen-coding-support.html#shortcuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find live templates with the description in `File` | `Settings` | `Live Templates`.

There is no printable reference available, however one can try to generate one basing on the XML files that can be found in `RUBYMINE\lib\rubymine.jar\liveTemplates`.

There is a [plug-in generating PDF keymap reference](https://github.com/denis-zhdanov/intellij-keymap), one can use it as a starting point for a new plug-in that will export PDF for the live templates.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder for answering my question that the nitpicking gods thought was "not a question". Your answer on the non-existant question sure helped me anyway!